# SQL SELECT from a many-to-many relationship exactly matching a set of rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database in an Android application with conversations and participants tables.  I want a query that, given a list of participants, returns only those conversations whose participant list is an exact match of the given list of participants.  For example, given these tables:

```
CONVERSATIONS    CONVERSATION_PARTICIPANTS
-------------    -------------------------
id               conversation_id name
--               --------------- ----
 1               1               u1 
 2               1               u2
 3               2               u1
 4               3               u1
```

I expect the following outputs ([participants input] => [conversations output]):

- [u1] => [2, 3]
- [u2] => []
- [u1, u2] => [1]

I have seen solutions that involve concatenating ordered lists of participant names, but I'd rather not go that route if possible.  Is such a thing possible?  Without temporary tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether two sets are *not* equal, based on individual items, you have to check if there exists, in either set, any item that does not exist in the other set.

Assuming we have a table `Input(name)`, it could be implemented like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM Conversations
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Conversation_Participants
                  WHERE conversation_id = Conversations.id
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM Input
                                    WHERE name = Conversation_Participants.name))
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Input
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM Conversation_Participants
                                    WHERE conversation_id = Conversations.id
                                      AND name = Input.name))
```

If you do not want to use a (temporary) table for `Input`, you can replace it with a subquery that returns the values on the fly:

```
... FROM Input ...
... FROM (SELECT 'u1' AS Name UNION ALL SELECT 'u2') AS Input ...
```